# While loop continues despite conditions not being met?

Tags: ruby, loops

When I run the game and type either "yes" or "no" at the end, it always reverts back to the start of the `while` loop at line 41, when the conditions for both that and the containing loop are not met.

```
replay = true
while replay

  #Pre-var
  print "What difficulty? (1 for easy, 2 for medium, or 3 for hard): "
  difficulty = gets.chomp.to_i
  until difficulty == 1 || difficulty == 2 || difficulty == 3 do
    print "Please type either 1, 2, or 3: "
    difficulty = gets.chomp.to_i  
  end

  #Variables
  if difficulty == 1
    r = Random.new
    number = r.rand(100..1000)
    puts "You have 15 guesses. "
    print "Guess a number with three digits: "
    within_num = 50
  elsif difficulty == 2
    r = Random.new
    number = r.rand(1000..10000)
    puts "You have 15 guesses. "
    print "Guess a number with four digits: "
    within_num = 500
  elsif difficulty == 3
    r = Random.new
    number = r.rand(10000..100000)
    puts "You have 15 guesses. "
    print "Guess a number with five digits: "
    within_num = 5000
  end
  guess = ""
  num_guess = 0
  guess_array = Array.new
  array_location = 0
  count_through = 0
  array_print = count_through - 1
  replay_inner = true

  #Body
  puts number
  while num_guess <= 14 || replay_inner == true #Keeping as <= 14 as to avoid unnecessarily rewriting code, still gives 15 guesses
    guess = gets.chomp.to_i
    if guess > number * 2
      print "That is more than double the number. Guess again: "
    elsif guess < number / 2
      print "That is less than half the number. Guess again: "
    elsif guess > number && guess < number + within_num #within_num: 50 for easy, 500 for medium, 5000 for hard
      print "You are close. That is too big. Guess again: "
    elsif guess < number && guess > number - within_num
      print "You are close. That is too small. Guess again: "
    elsif guess < number
      print "That is too small. Guess again: "                #Hinting the user to how close they are.
    elsif guess > number
      print "That is too big. Guess again: "
    elsif guess == number
      puts "Congragulations! You win!"
      print "Your "
      print guess_array.length
      print " incorrect guesses were: "

      if num_guess == 0
        sleep(0.5)
        print "... Oh."
      else
        while count_through < num_guess #Loop to relay user's guesses with a delay of 0.5 seconds
          print guess_array[count_through] 

          if count_through == num_guess - 2
            print ", and "
          elsif count_through == num_guess - 1
            puts ". "
          else 
            print ", "
          end

          count_through += 1
          sleep(0.5)     
        end

        puts "Would you like to play again? (yes/no)"
        replay_answer = gets.chomp
        until replay_answer == "yes" || replay_answer == "y" || replay_answer == "no" || replay_answer == "n" do
          print "Please answer with yes, y, no, or n: "
          replay_answer = gets.chomp
        end

        if replay_answer == "yes" || replay_answer == "y"
          replay = true
          puts "yes"
        elsif replay_answer == "no" || replay_answer == "n" #Determining whether or not to replay
          replay = false
          puts "no"
        end
      end
    end

    guess_array.push guess
    num_guess += 1
    #puts num_guess
    #puts guess_array[array_location]
    array_location += 1
    if num_guess >= 15 && guess != number
      puts "Sorry, you lost. "
      print "Your "
      print guess_array.size
      print " guesses were: "

      while count_through < num_guess
        print guess_array[count_through] #Same as loop above; for when player fails to guess correctly

        if count_through == num_guess - 2
          print ", and "
        elsif count_through == num_guess - 1
          puts ". "
        else 
          print ", "
        end 

        count_through += 1
        sleep(0.5)
      end

      puts "Would you like to play again? (yes/no)"
      replay_answer = gets.chomp
      until replay_answer == "yes" || replay_answer == "y" || replay_answer == "no" || replay_answer == "n" do
        print "Please answer with yes, y, no, or n: "
        replay_answer = gets.chomp
      end

      if replay_answer == "yes" || replay_answer == "y"
        replay = true
        replay_inner = true
        puts "yes"
      elsif replay_answer == "no" || replay_answer == "n" #Determining whether or not to replay
        replay = false
        replay_inner = false
        puts "no"
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: Your `end`s keep not matching up. If you indent things correctly it might help track down the issue.

Comment: Was replay declared as a boolean?

Comment: Sorry, with the constant restructuring of the code (as my instructor tells us to add or implement certain things) it gets a little disorganized.

Comment: replay is declared as true at the start of the code. If I'm correct, you don't have to declare variables in Ruby, but even if the while loop is `replay == true` it doesn't work.

Comment: Please reformat this code to include correct indentation. It's pretty unreadable as is.

Comment: I'm sorry, I cannot do that. I have very limited time right now, trying to do it within Stack Overflow is nearly impossible, and copy-pasting screws it up anyways.

Comment: Copy pasting doesn't screw it up, you just paste the code, select it and click the button to format it as code, which will add the 4 spaces to the start of every line. If you want people to help you, make it easy for them!

Comment: The very last end is for the while loop containing the entire code. Thank you.

Comment: In the future, break programs like this up into small methods. It will reduce the amount of nested loops needed and it will be much easier to keep track of what is happening. If you have learned about objects yet, use them.

Comment: You might want to look into using a real code editor, like [(g)vim](http://www.vim.org/),  or [Sublime Text 2](http://www.sublimetext.com/2). They work on Windows, Mac OS and Linux, and support the exact same command-sequences across OSes. gvim and Sublime both use a mouse also. Both have the ability to reindent source code, which is the first step in tracking down bugs in code just to see if your blocks and methods are terminated correctly. Other editors exist, but those are two very useful tools.

Comment: I reformatted your code but the indentation shows you're missing a closing `end`.

Comment: This is only the fourth simple program we've done, and it's a simple High School course. The missing end is because somebody else reformatted it and removed it... Gah. I am using Netbeans in my class, and Eclipse at home.

Answer (score 0):

I think the condition in the `while` should be:

```
numberGuess<=14 && replay_inner == true
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you and *especially* your fellow programmers will find this and future bugs is by properly commenting your code, e.g.:

```
# ask the user about an optional replay
replay_answer = gets.chomp

# only accept yes/y/no/n
until replay_answer == "yes" || replay_answer == "y" || replay_answer == "no" || replay_answer == "n" do
  print "Please answer with yes, y, no, or n: "
  replay_answer = gets.chomp
end

## recoded this to a case, as I think it's much nicer :)

# determining whether to replay or to stop the loop
case replay_answer
  when "yes", "y"
    replay = true
    puts "yes"
  when "no", "n"
    replay = false
    puts "no"

    replay_inner = false
end
```

Comment: We haven't learned about cases in Ruby yet, but I'm familiar with them in Java. There is code that changes `replay_inner` to false.

Comment: oops, I missed that, was kinda tired :P

Comment: allthough this surprises me, as I copy/pasted your code into my answer... maybe somebody edited it out temporarily... :/

Comment: Yeah, someone edited it and removed a bunch of things accidentally.

Answer (score 0):

I've modified a little your code, you should really use some decent editor with at least syntax errors highlighting. I've changed `OR` to `AND` condition in inner loop (comment in code) and added way of breaking from it when guessed number. I've also removed second occurence of code responsible of playing again, remember, DRY yourself.

```
replay = true
while replay
  p replay
  #Pre-var
  print "What difficulty? (1 for easy, 2 for medium, or 3 for hard): "
  difficulty = gets.chomp.to_i
  until difficulty == 1 || difficulty == 2 || difficulty == 3 do
    print "Please type either 1, 2, or 3: "
    difficulty = gets.chomp.to_i
  end

  #Variables
  if difficulty == 1
    r = Random.new
    number = r.rand(100..1000)
    puts "You have 15 guesses. "
    print "Guess a number with three digits: "
    within_num = 50
  elsif difficulty == 2
    r = Random.new
    number = r.rand(1000..10000)
    puts "You have 15 guesses. "
    print "Guess a number with four digits: "
    within_num = 500
  elsif difficulty == 3
    r = Random.new
    number = r.rand(10000..100000)
    puts "You have 15 guesses. "
    print "Guess a number with five digits: "
    within_num = 5000
  end
  guess = ""
  num_guess = 0
  guess_array = Array.new
  array_location = 0
  count_through = 0
  array_print = count_through - 1
  replay_inner = true

  #Body
  puts number
  while num_guess <= 14 && replay_inner == true #Keeping as <= 14 as to avoid unnecessarily rewriting code, still gives 15 guesses
    guess = gets.chomp.to_i
    if guess > number * 2
      print "That is more than double the number. Guess again: "
    elsif guess < number / 2
      print "That is less than half the number. Guess again: "
    elsif guess > number && guess < number + within_num #within_num: 50 for easy, 500 for medium, 5000 for hard
      print "You are close. That is too big. Guess again: "
    elsif guess < number && guess > number - within_num
      print "You are close. That is too small. Guess again: "
    elsif guess < number
      print "That is too small. Guess again: " #Hinting the user to how close they are.
    elsif guess > number
      print "That is too big. Guess again: "
    elsif guess == number
      puts "Congragulations! You win!"
      print "Your "
      print guess_array.length
      print " incorrect guesses were: "
      if num_guess == 0
        sleep(0.5)
        print "... Oh."
      else
        while count_through < num_guess #Loop to relay user's guesses with a delay of 0.5 seconds
          print guess_array[count_through]
          if count_through == num_guess - 2
            print ", and "
          elsif count_through == num_guess - 1
            puts ". "
          else
            print ", "
          end
          count_through += 1
          sleep(0.5)
        end
      end
      replay_inner = false # or just `break`, you have to break somehow from inner loop here
    end

    guess_array.push guess
    num_guess += 1
    #puts num_guess
    #puts guess_array[array_location]
    array_location += 1
    if num_guess >= 15 && guess != number
      puts "Sorry, you lost. "
      print "Your "
      print guess_array.size
      print " guesses were: "
      while count_through < num_guess
        print guess_array[count_through] #Same as loop above; for when player fails to guess correctly
        if count_through == num_guess - 2
          print ", and "
        elsif count_through == num_guess - 1
          puts ". "
        else
          print ", "
        end
        count_through += 1
        sleep(0.5)
      end
    end
  end



   puts "\nWould you like to play again? (yes/no)"
  replay_answer = gets.chomp
  until replay_answer == "yes" || replay_answer == "y" || replay_answer == "no" || replay_answer == "n" do
    print "Please answer with yes, y, no, or n: "
    replay_answer = gets.chomp
  end
  if replay_answer == "yes" || replay_answer == "y"
    replay = true
    replay_inner = true
    puts "yes"
  elsif replay_answer == "no" || replay_answer == "n" #Determining whether or not to replay
    replay = false
    replay_inner = false
    puts "no"
  end

end
```

Comment: This is a high school thing - we're stuck using Netbeans. Unfortunately, because of that, I'll have to wait until Tuesday to see if the full program works.

Comment: 'Full program' means...? If there are other parts you can checkout it from git, you're using some (d)vcs, aren't you? ;) If no. you can simply copy above code, paste into any_name.rb and run `ruby any_name.rb` to start it, you don't need specific IDE for that.

Comment: There are other parts of the program that can interfere with this code.